# Operation overload two objects?

Tags: c++, file-io, comparison

i'm trying to read in two text files that contains weight and height then storing them into a vector. afterwards, i want to check if theyre equal. for example if one text has 90 weight, 10 height and another text file has 50 weight and 12 height. how do i go about this? thanks

```
  #include <iostream>
        #include <vector>
        #include <cstdlib>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;
        class Person{

            public:
                Person();
                Person(int weight, int height);

            bool operator ==(const Person& e);

            private:
                int weight;
                int height;
        };

        void readFile(string file, std::vector<Person>&p);

        int main(){
            std::vector<Person>p;
            std::vector<Person>e;

            readFile("person1.txt", p);
            readFile("person2.txt", e);

            (p==e);
            return 0;
        }

        Person::Person(int weight, int height){
            weight = weight;
            height = height;
        };

        bool Person::operator ==(const Person& e)
        {
            return ((weight== e.weight)
                    && (height== e.height));
        }

        void readFile(string file, std::vector<Person>&p){
            int height1;
            int weight1;
            ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open(file.c_str());
            if(inFile.fail()){
                cerr << "Error opening file.";
                exit(1);
            }
            while(!inFile.eof()){
                inFile >> height1 >> weight1;
                p.push_back(Person(height1, weight1));
            }
            inFile.close();
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?
Don't you mean in the second call to readFile to put Person e, not p?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you want to check if the all the  tuples in the two files are equal ?
2. Do you want to check atleast 1 tuple matches from each file ?

For case 1, just loop through the two vectors and see whether each object from the two vectors are same or not (you already have the '==' overload).

For case 2, pick one from vector1 and check with all from vector2, and repeat for all vector1 objects.

Also your `readFile` should **not** be a member function of class `Person`. Make it a stand-alone function.

Note: Declare the vectors in main and pass it to `readFile` and then check for equality accordingly.

**Edit**
The == operator overload should be

```
bool operator==(const Person&) const ; // since it does not mutate the object
bool Person::operator==(const Person& p) const
{ ... }
```

Comment: When I attempt to == the two vectors. It tells me that there are no matches for my operator?  Edited above.

Comment: Check the edit. Make readFile global. And also your constructor will not do any assignment. Refer to Olaf's answer.

Comment: sorry, how do i make it global?

Comment: Just declare the prototype outside the class definition i.e. declare after the class declaration ends. The definition is fine.

Comment: It gave me an error? Any idea why? thanks                                             error: passing 'const Person' as 'this' argument of 'bool Person::operator==(const Person&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 5 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Check my edit. The == operator overload should be a const member.

Answer (score 0):

OT, but your constructor won't work, because you just access the arguments `weight` and `height` and don't assign the members

```
Person::Person(int weight, int height){
    weight = weight;
    height = height;
};
```

You can rename the arguments, e.g. `w` and `h` or prefix with `this->`, if you want to keep the names

```
Person::Person(int weight, int height){
    this->weight = weight;
    this->height = height;
};
```

Another way would be to use member initialization

```
Person::Person(int weight, int height)
    : weight(weight), height(height)
{
};
```

To your question, since you cannot know which value is a weight and which one is a height, you can only see how many values are in there and compare if there are the same amount of integers in both files.